# Importing json file in typescript causing "Unexpected token" error with valid json

Tags: json, typescript

So i followed [this article](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) to try and import a json file into my code. Here is my import line:

`import data from './assets/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json';`

Here is the font json file (just to test if it will even import right now):

`{"hi":"true"}`

here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module":"es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "outDir": "dist/lib",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and here is the error i get when trying to compile:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token
src\assets\fonts\helvetiker_bold.typeface.json (1:5)
1: {"hi":"true"}
        ^
```

I have no clue what it is complaining about.. any help is appreciated

Comment: Personally I never managed to get this to work with `import` however the equivalent of `const data 
= require('./assets/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json')` seems to have worked for me as a workaround

Comment: @apokryfos I think i've tried that already. When i run the code in my browser i get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Maybe you need to switch `module` to `commonjs` to get this to work.

Comment: @apokryfos i have tried that aswell and still get the require is not defined error /: really wanting to look for a solution that doesn't need `require` because nothing i've tried makes require work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to just create a class that contained my JSON object and use it in combination with the `FontLoader.parse()` function instead of loading the JSON from a file. This was accomplished like so:

1. Created a file called `HelvetikerUtils.ts` that contained my json object:

```
export class HelvetikerUtil {
    constructor() { }

    data: any = <YOUR_FONT_JSON_HERE>
}
```

2. Import this class wherever

`import { HelvetikerUtil } from './HelvetikerUtil';`

3. Load the data using FontLoader.parse()

```
let myFont = new HelvetikerUtil;
let FONTLoader = new FontLoader();
let font = FONTLoader.parse(myFont.data);
```